# Bibtex: How to input accentuation on url?

Tags: bibtex, urls

I am trying to use bibtex to output the url from a reference, but it's not working because the  url has accentuation, just like below:

```
url = {http://www.epe.gov.br/mercado/Documents/Série\%20Estudos\%20de\%20Energia/20130117_1.pdf},
```

The output is:

```
http://www.epe.gov.br/mercado/Documents/S\unhbox\voidb@x\ bgroup\let\unhbox\voidb@x\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{e\global\ mathchardef\accent@spacefactor\spacefactor}\accent19e\ egroup\spacefactor\accent@spacefactorrie%20Estudos%20de% 20Energia/20130117_1.pdf
```

Is there a way to protect the accentuation when it enters on url environment?

Comment: Use a correct URL: [http://www.epe.gov.br/mercado/Documents/S%C3%A9rie%20Estudos%20de%20Energia/20130117_1.pdf](http://www.epe.gov.br/mercado/Documents/S%C3%A9rie%20Estudos%20de%20Energia/20130117_1.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this other site. Where can I find this percentage substitutions for accentuations and special characters?

Comment: Could you please change you user name to a unique one? We already have another [Werner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An URL should not contain accented characters (cf. [Uniform resource locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#List_of_allowed_URL_characters) or [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)).

In your URL, replace accented characters by encoded characters:

```
http://www.epe.gov.br/mercado/Documents/S%C3%A9rie%20Estudos%20de%20Energia/20130117_1.pdf
```

Edit: [Fast reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for encoded characters.

Comment: The problem with encoded characters is that they obscures the URL such that one can't know what it actually is without a browser. This might be a problem if the work will be printed and the reader is supposed to enter the URL by hand (and is expected to have the input method for the language).

Comment: @ImperishableNight Extract from RFC 3986: _A URI is composed from a limited set of characters consisting of digits, letters, and a few graphic symbols._ This set does not contain any accented character!

Comment: Then [RFC 3987](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3987) happened and defined the Internationalized Resource Identifier (IRI). You may argue that it's not "true" URL (the % escaped sequence is), but every modern browser accepts them, and they made my life browsing Chinese wikis a _lot_ merrier.

Comment: @ImperishableNight Modern browsers can accept IRIs ... but PDF specifications only know URLs.

Comment: Which, I guess, means that we want to _show_ the IRI but _jump_ to the URL when clicked on. I mean, the second part is optional, you can't click on a printed document anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If I use `\usepackage[]{hyperref}` before `\begin{document}` and use in my bibliography e.g. `url = {http://www.de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyoncé_Knowles}`, then everything runs without problems. 
But it is difficult to say if the `hyperref`-package helps in your case because you do not tell us which packages you are using.