# How to enter an URL with Chinese Characters?

Tags: urls, chinese

I cannot figure out how to include a url with Chinese characters in my tex file. This is the URL: [https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/中国大陆报纸列表](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E5%A4%A7%E9%99%86%E6%8A%A5%E7%BA%B8%E5%88%97%E8%A1%A8).

(Sorry, apparently I need at least 10 reputation points to post more than 2 links so in the following I refer to https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/ as ROOTURL)

I only get errors when I've tried the following :

- `\url{ROOTURL}`
- `\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}\url{ROOTURL/中国大陆报纸列表}\end{CJK*}`
- `\url{\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}ROOTURL/中国大陆报纸列表\end{CJK*}}`
- `\url{ROOTURL\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}中国大陆报纸列表\end{CJK*}}`

It looks like only this is possible:
`\url{ROOTURL}\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}中国大陆报纸列表\end{CJK*}`

The problem with this approach is that the full url is not hyperrefed. If anybody knows of a way to get around this, that'd be great, thanks!

Comment: Welcome.  I've marked up the code in your post to make it a little easier to read.  [Bibtex: How to input accentuation on url?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97340/bibtex-how-to-input-accentuation-on-url) is a question that may have some bearing on your case.  The section [Internationalized URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Internationalized_URL) in the relevant wikipedia article provides background.  Also you should probably provide a complete minimum document -- the packages you use and the options you pass to them are likely to be important

Comment: @ccheng623, please enter next time a short but complete Latex code which shows your problem (\documentclass ... \end{document}). Then we can copy and compile, AND we see, which packages you do use or might be missing.